# for loop if file doesn't exist go to next record

Tags: r

I have the following code and for some reason I can not get it to go to the next record.  I put the print(innallURL) before the if(!file.exists) command and I get all the urls, I put it after where it is no, and nothing shows up, so that makes me think the files are failing the file.exists part.  I've test 5 of the URLs and they work/exist in the web directory.  I've used the next in other loops and have not had any problems.  I also tried adding url= in fron of the string.  I've searched here, but I can only find the formula I'm using in the examples.  Please point out what idiotic thing I'm overlooking.  ha!  Thanks!

```
gidURLs <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(allGids)))

#get pitches

#set filename

for (thisgidURL in gidURLs) {

innallURL = paste(thisgidURL, "inning/inning_all.xml", sep="")

  if (!file.exists(innallURL)) next

print(innallURL)

pitches <- read_xml(innallURL)

# get all at-bats ---------------------------------------------------------

atbat <- xml_find_all(pitches, "//atbat")

# make a giant data frame -------------------------------------------------

bind_rows(lapply(atbat, function(x) {

  pitches <- xml_find_all(x, "./pitch")

bind_rows(lapply(pitches, function(y) {
  data.frame(t(xml_attrs(y)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})) -> pitch_dat

pitch_dat$atbat_num <- xml_attr(x, "num")

pitch_dat

})) -> bats

game_id = substr(url, 66, 95)
bats$game_id <- game_id

allbatsdf <- data.frame(bats)
allbats <- rbind(bats, allbats)

}
```

example innallURLs from the list when its printed before the file.exists command.

```
"http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2015/month_01/day_30/gid_2015_01_30_magwin_oriwin_1/inning/inning_all.xml"
"http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2015/month_01/day_31/gid_2015_01_31_sydwin_prtwin_1/inning/inning_all.xml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use httr package to use `GET` method.

```
library(httr)
if(GET(innallURL)$status_code!=200) next
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Frustrating being a noob to r that something that simple didn't show up anywhere else.  Guess I wasn't using the right keywords.